# Why does someone edit a review or another's answers?

Tags: discussion

I'm just curious. I just saw an [edited version](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/posts/31253/revisions) of an answer I posted to someone. I'm just curious why there is any editing. Is this platform that vain? People's answers are real and personal and not always grammatically correct, but they are real. The revision of my answer looks like a college student going for dissertation or something, but it just seems weird. Part of our difference in this world where everyone isn't the same is that some of us aren't the best writers and that's ok. Again, very nice edit and just curious why the need...

Comment: This question belongs in meta.  This platform prides itself on being the number one place on the Web for questions and answers. Edits are part of the process of improving and maintaining the site quality.

Comment: "college student going for dissertation or something" the edit added *paragraphs*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Over-editing of post](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/929/over-editing-of-post) (answer https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/929/over-editing-of-post/930#930 seems particularly on point)

Answer (score 3):

<sub>Since I'm the culprit responsible for the edit, I feel like I should answer your question to the best of my abilities.</sub>

---

I edited in paragraphs to improve readability. There is also a [comment](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/31217/between-parents-and-marijuana-smoking-sister/31253#comment64806_31253) showing that another user thought paragraphs would be an improvement.

---

> Almost every piece of writing you do that is longer than a few sentences should be organized into paragraphs. This is because paragraphs show a reader where the subdivisions of an essay begin and end, and thus help the reader see the organization of the essay and grasp its main points.

*Source:* [Writing Tutorial Services, Indiana University, Bloomington, IN](https://wts.indiana.edu/writing-guides/paragraphs-and-topic-sentences.html)

---

> Suitable design solutions decrease extraneous cognitive load and support
>   comprehension by supporting mental model formation.

*Source:* Passera, S. (2015). Beyond the wall of text: How information design can make contracts user-friendly. In: A. Marcus (Ed.), Design, User Experience, and Usability: Users and Interactions (pp. 341-352). Lecture Notes in Computer Science. Cham, Switzerland: Springer International Publishing. DOI: 10.1007/978-3-319-20898-5_33
[Link](https://aaltodoc.aalto.fi/handle/123456789/27292) (scroll down to "Files in this item", article2.pdf)

Comment: I don't think OP is complaining about you editing his answer. [Quote]Again, very nice edit[/Quote], but is wondering if it is really necessary to have such a tool in stackexchange.

Comment: U are correct. Not complaining. Some of us will feel intimidated being that we aren't that great at writing and what seems clear as day to u might seem like greek or Chinese to me. If you guys want to edit and love to do it, I'm happy to have mine edited. Thank u.